# What am I seeing in htop on Linux?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, top, htop

Not sure if this is the right place for this question but I'll ask it anyway and see where it lands!

I have a node process running on Centos and when I run `htop`, I see a whole bunch of processes that look related but I don't know how and I'm hoping someone can explain it to me :-/

Take a look at this screen shot ....

[image]

I only have one "realtime-event-manager" process running and yet I see multiple. I understand that this is a representation of the underlying multi-threading that's going on but what I don't understand is why the the `CPU`, `MEM` and `RES` values are all equal? What am I actually seeing here?

Also, notice the CPU utilisation bars at the top. I often see them spike to 90-100% but with no noticeable slow down... is this a true representation or is it just the SUM of the items listed in `htop`?

Comment: For clarity, please could you enable the `PPID` column and update the picture?

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10403/108618).

Comment: @Attie... sure give me 10 mins just in a meeting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only have one "realtime-event-manager" process running and yet I see multiple.

Linux, threads are implemented as [LWPs - Light-Weight Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_process) meaning that Thread IDs and Process IDs are actually allocated from the same pool. See this answer for good information: [Difference between PID and TID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8787888/1347519).

You can toggle nested / tree view by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Additionally, you can show / hide user-space threads by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, or via the setup menu - <kbd>F2</kbd>

[image: htop setup - thread visibility]

It's also beneficial to enable the "*Show custom thread names*" option.

These "*processes*" you are seeing are probably actually "*threads*" - this would be more clear in tree view, or with the "*Display threads in a different color*" option enabled.

---

> the CPU utilisation bars at the top. I often see them spike to 90-100% but with no noticeable slow down

In the *nix world, 100% means "*100% of one core*"... it doesn't mean "*100% of all available processing time*" like it does on Windows.

Additionally, "*no noticeable slow down*" is a very interesting and subjective point.

Depending on the kernel's [preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)), scheduler and priorities the system can be tweaked and optimised for:

- "*realtime*" - an attempt at ["*soft realtime*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) scheduling... (NB: Linux is not a realtime kernel)
- "*interactive*" - will more readily preempt (interrupt) processes to give the appearance of a more responsive system
- "*batch*" - will hold off on the interruption in an attempt to complete a large job more efficiently, at the expense of making the user wait.

Most user-facing systems these days optimise for interactive scheduling, as do more and more servers.

Additionally, I have observed "*bigger*" / "*better*" processors (e.g: i7 / Xeon) offer much better responsiveness under high load than "*smaller*" processors (e.g: Atom / i3)... I can't fully explain this, but it could be due to thread count, cache size, etc...

Comment: While you're on the settings screen, I'd also select "Show custom thread names", then the listing actually becomes somewhat useful. (Threads can be toggled via Shift+H.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Really helped. Pressing `F5` shed some light on the situation. Any idea why each child thread shows as using the same amount of `Mem` and `CPU` % as the parent process though? That can't be correct surely?

Comment: Threads are grouped into the parent process, and all share the same address space. Thus the memory usage is the same for all threads in a process. CPU usage is correctly reported per-thread (in your example 15838 is using 47.8%, while the others are using 0%)